# NHibernate - one-to-one relationship

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a problem with one-to-one relationships in NHibernate. The structures of the my objects are as follows:

```
public partial class PersonDataContext
{
    protected int _personid;
    protected string _name;
    protected EmployeeDataContext _employee;
}



public partial class EmployeeDataContext
{
    protected int _personid;
    protected string _payrollno;
}
```

In my model, every PersonDataContext must contain exactly one EmployeeDataContext, and every EmployeeDataContext that exists is there to be part of an PersonDataContext . It's a common one-to-one relationship.

Now, to the mappings:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="PersonDataContext, DAL" table="`Person`" lazy="false">
        <id name="PersonId" column="`PersonId`" type="int">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property type="string" name="name" column="`name`" />
        <one-to-one name="Employee" cascade="save-update" class="EmployeeDataContext,DAL" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>


<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="EmployeeDataContext, DAL" table="`Employee`" lazy="false">
        <id name="PersonId" column="`PersonId`">
            <generator class="foreign">
                <param name="property" >PersonId</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property type="string" length="30" name="PayRollNo" column="`PayRollNo`" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Then I create an PersonDataContext, that creates by itself an EmployeeDataContext. Then when I save it NHibernate throws an exception, **"Unable to resolve property: PersonId".**

Comment: Please add the other partial classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a PersonId property in EmployeeDataContext.

You should have a PersonDataContext property of type PersonDataContext, and that's what goes in the param.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I've added a PersonDataContext property in EmployeeDataContext and changed that param as well. After these changes it throws below exception:                             attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property: Person                            (Person is my property name)

Comment: Suggestion: read http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone

Comment: Thanks mate. Just another quick question. I've assigned the person and it doesn't throw exceptions any more. It saves a person record but it doesn't save the employee! :(

Comment: I've tried with cascade="all" and cascade="save-update" but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

The foreign property error, modify 'PersonId' to 'PersonDataContext' as follow:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
     <class name="EmployeeDataContext, DAL" table="`Employee`" lazy="false">
         <id name="PersonId" column="`PersonId`">
             <generator class="foreign">
                 <param name="property" >**PersonDataContext**</param>
             </generator>
         </id>
         <property type="string" length="30" name="PayRollNo" column="`PayRollNo`" />
     </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```